# Instagram oauth flow in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0, instagram-api

I am using angularJs and rending a button to let user authorize to instagram.

I can test by passing https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token  iI get the accessToken in the redirectUrl.

The question is how do I invoke this flow in angularJs button click. Currently what I have is as follows:

html
  Authorize to Instagram

js

```
app.controller('AdminController', ['$scope', function($scope){
...
    this.authorizeIg = function(){
            console.log('start of authorizeIg implict flow');
            window.location.href = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token";
        };
```

The above will just redirect me to redirect_url after authentication. So, I do not know how to invoke that url within the function and return back a response containing accessToken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single button click would only redirect the webpage to generate an access token but not save it. Instagram doesn't return a response result with the access token.

```
"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token";
```

In angularJS, adding a `redirect_uri` in above such as : `http://localhost/angularapp/:accessToken`
would redirect your application to this Uri with link such as: `http://localhost/angularapp/#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` on successful authentication.

You could catch this token in the application by using `$routeParams` directive of angular.

`$scope.token = $routeParams.accessToken` as defined explicitly in your redirect_uri.

Comment: the problem is that i am using ng-view which makes the url like host:port/myapppage#admin   and  ig dont like it as a valid uri.

I wanted a popup to open and then finish up authentication get access token etc and close it

Comment: Does this help: https://www.liquidint.com/blog/angularjs-and-instagram-a-single-page-application-with-oauth2/